# Representing a Vuforia AR Camera in UML (Unity Project)

Tags: unity-game-engine, uml, vuforia

I have a unity project which makes use of Qualcomm's Vuforia Augmented Reality API. I'm wandering what the best way to represent this in an UML Diagram would be?
My original thoughts where to represent it either as a package or an interface, but after researching further I have confused myself somewhat!
I need the UML diagram to show connections with classes that are attached ( as scripts) to the AR camera Instance within unity.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with a couple of computing academic staff on this, it has been suggested that the best way to do this is to represent the AR camera as a package, and only include the classes that are relevant to the design (I.E Those that are accessed from other scripts, or that have been changed) in the UML Diagram. However be sure to include a footnote to explain that the UML diagram is not a complete representation of the package, to avoid confusion.